Import S&P data from Mexico with GetSymbols
I am using GetSymbols to import financial data from Yahoo Finance, I understand that the ticket I should use is the one that appears on the Yahoo Finance page next to the name, however, I want to import the data from the S&P Mexico ADR and the ticket that appears is "^BKMXT", but when running it says that the data cannot be imported. Is there something I'm doing wrong? Or should I use another ticket to be able to work with this data?
I am using the following code in R in Google Colab[1]:
getSymbols("^BKCMX", src = "yahoo", from = "2020-01-01", to = "2020-01-30", periodicity = "monthly")

[1] Edited. Original: Estoy usando el siguiente código en R de google colab
